# Does LoadRunner use native or green vuser threads?

Tags: multithreading, loadrunner, green-threads

I set up 100 virtual users for a Windows version of LoadRunner, with the 'Run vuser as a thread' option enabled.

I then used [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) on `wlrun.exe` (the LoadRunner Controller process) to see if the `Threads` metric for this process increased while the 100 vusers ran... either by 100, or by 100-k in case LR was utilizing thread pooling.

The thread count did not seem to increase at all!

Can I, therefore, safely conclude that LoadRunner uses green threads instead of native ones?

Comment: No idea, why this got downvoted!

Answer (score 0):

You were monitoring the wrong process.  wlrun is the Console.  You need to be monitoring the multi-threaded driver of the load generator software.   The name of the multi-threded driver is covered both in the literature as well as training.

Also, it is considered a bad practice to stage your load on the same host as the controller

Answer (score 0):

As James pointed out the process was the wrong one. The correct one (for standalone controller without LoadGenerator) is "mmdrv.exe".  The number of threads it spawns is NOT configurable, but has been seen to be around 50 threads/process. These threads AFAIK are normal windows threads.